# Clarification on reduce to create filter in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

My main goal for academic purposes is to [solve this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954347/using-reduce-to-build-a-filter-function-in-javascript) and for the most part I did. Also I wanted to make sure that I was not missing a fundamental part of reduce by not understanding what is wrong with my code.

This is how I would solve it, I've attached my reduce function as well as filter function. I believe my reduce function works however, my filter function isn't quite working so well as I can't pass my test cases.

1) Why am i not hitting the last element of the array?

I've noticed that prev and curr actually never return 5 at any point of the reduce function. Am I missing something in my reduce function?

```html
myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

function each(collection, action){
 if(Array.isArray(collection)){
  for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i ++){
   action(collection[i]);
  }
 }
 else if(typeof(collection) === "object"){
  for (var property in collection){
   action(collection[property]);
  }
 }
}

function reduce(collection, combine, start){
 each(collection, function(element){
  if(start === undefined){
   return start = element;
  }
  else {
   return start = combine(start, element);
  }
 });
 return start;
}


function filterR(collection, predicate){
 var aR = [];
 reduce(collection, function(prev, curr){
  if(predicate(prev)){
   aR.push(prev);
  }
  if(predicate(curr)){
   aR.push(curr);
  }
  
 });
 return aR;
}


console.log(filter(myArray, function(val){return val % 5 === 0;})); //expected [5]
console.log(filter(myArray, function(val){return val <= 5;})); //expected [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: are you going to share your `each` function

Comment: @naomik Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Why am i not hitting the last element of the array?

I don't know. It might be an error in your each-function, wich is not posted here. But since you have some more flaws in boh of your functions, I'll add a working implementation.

> I've noticed that prev and curr actually never return 5 at any point of the reduce function.

prev and curr never return anything, they are arguments. And that particular function itself, also doesn't ever return anything.

First `start === undefined` is no proper check to determine wether yo want to initialize the result-value with the first(current)-element. `undefined` is an unexpected, even unwanted value in that place, but it is actually perfectly fine. So with that check, your reduce-function might start over again, in the middle of the collection.

Just take a look at the previously mentioned function you utilize in filter. This function does return `undefined` (as the value for the next iteration) ;) so that `prev` will always be `undefined` in your code.

Then, reduce makes no sense in your filter-function, at least the way you use it. You use it as `each`.

```
function reduce(collection, combine, start){
    var result = start, hasValue = arguments.length > 2;

    each(collection, function(element){
        if(hasValue){
            result = combine(result, element);
        }else{
            result = element;
            hasValue = true;
        }
    });

    if(!hasValue){
        //no start/default-value, no elements in the collection,
        //what result do you expect from this reduce-task?
        throw new Error("reduce of empty array with no initial value");     
    }
    return result;
}

function filter(collection, predicate){
    return reduce(collection, function(result, elm){
        //the functional-approach: no mutations
        return predicate(elm)?
            result.concat( [elm] ):
            result;

        //or a more sane way to do this in JS
        if( predicate(elm) ) result.push( elm );
        return result;
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't diagnose your problem because I don't know what your `each` procedure is.
>
> Anyway, it doesn't matter; you're overthinking it.

`reduce` is very simple to implement by hand.

```
function reduce(f, start, arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0)
    return start;
  else
    return reduce(f, f(start, arr[0]), arr.slice(1));
}

// example
function add(x,y) { return x+y; }
reduce(add, 0, []);      //=> 0
reduce(add, 0, [1,2,3]); //=> 6
```

I see that you are trying to support a sort of reduce without an optional starting value. That is impossible if your reduce function is to be considered a [total function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function#Total_function). A starting value is **required**. Don't try to be clever.

---

Now a `filter` implemented using `reduce`

```
function filter(f, arr) {
  return reduce(function(result, x) {
    if (f(x))
      return result.concat([x]);
    else
      return result;
  }, [], arr);
}
```

Your examples

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

filter(function(val){return val % 5 === 0;}, myArray)
//=> [5]

filter(function(val){return val <= 5;}, myArray)
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

**If you want to learn more...**

There are other ways to implement `reduce` as well. One such improvement you could make is to put the recursion in [tail position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). When JavaScript engines support tail call elimination (with ES6), this would prevent `reduce` from stack-overflowing for significantly large values of `arr`.

```
function reduce(f, start, arr) {
  function loop(result, arr) {
    if (arr.length === 0)
      return result;
    else
      return loop(f(result, arr[0]), arr.slice(1));
  }
  return loop(start, arr);
}
```

**A blackhole appears...**

With `reduce` and [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) under your belt, you now stand at the shores of the deep, vast sea that is [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) and [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). If you're feeling very zealous, you can explore how [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and [combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) change this definition even more dramatically.

The following code is written in ES6

```
// U-combinator
const U = f=> f(f);

// Y-combinator
const Y = U (h=> f=> f (x=> h (h) (f) (x)));

// reduce
const reduce = f=> Y(h=> start=> arr=>
  arr.length === 0
    ? start
    : h (f (start) (arr[0])) (arr.slice(1)));


// filter
const filter = f=>
  reduce(result=> x=>
    f(x) ? result.concat([x]) : result) ([]);

// your examples again...
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
filter (x=> x % 5 === 0) (myArray) //=> [5]
filter (x=> x <= 5) (myArray)      //=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```